# Get max and std over array-fields in dataframe column pandas

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy, std

(Pandas version 1.1.1.)

I have arrays as entries in the cells of a Dataframe column.

```
a = np.array([1,8])
b = np.array([5,14])
df = pd.DataFrame({'float':[1,2], 'array': [a,b]})

>    float    array
> 0      1   [1, 8]
> 1      2  [5, 14]
```

Now I need some statistics over each array position.

It works perfectly with the mean:

```
df['array'].mean()
> array([ 3., 11.])
```

But if I try to do it with the maximum or the standard deviation error occur:

```
df['array'].std()
> setting an array element with a sequence.

df['array'].max()
> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It seems like .mean() .std() ánd .max() are constructed differently. Anyhow, has someone an idea how to caluculate the std and max (and min etc), without dividing the array into several columns?

(The DataFrame has array's of different shapes. But I do only want to caluculate statistics within a .groupyby() over rows where the arrays do have the same shape.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert columns to 2d arrays and use numpy for count:

```
a = np.array([1,8])
b = np.array([5,14])
df = pd.DataFrame({'float':[1,2], 'array': [a,b]})

#2k for test
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


In [150]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df['array'].tolist(), index=df.index).std())
4.25 ms ± 305 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [151]: %timeit (np.std(np.array(df['array'].tolist()), ddof=1, axis=0))
944 µs ± 1.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

```
In [152]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df['array'].tolist(), index=df.index).max())
4.31 ms ± 646 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [153]: %timeit (np.max(np.array(df['array'].tolist()), axis=0))
836 µs ± 1.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For 20k rows:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [155]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df['array'].tolist(), index=df.index).std())
35.3 ms ± 87.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [156]: %timeit (np.std(np.array(df['array'].tolist()), ddof=1, axis=0))
9.13 ms ± 170 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
In [157]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df['array'].tolist(), index=df.index).max())
35.3 ms ± 127 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [158]: %timeit (np.max(np.array(df['array'].tolist()), axis=0))
8.21 ms ± 27.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you, but these are std and max per array. 

But I need std and max over all 1st-array-entries, all 2nd, etc...

Comment: @ThomasR - hmm, so if use `b = np.array([5,14, 12])` and `a` is same, then also `print (df['array'].mean())` failed?

Comment: The results I need are:
(5,14) for the max and 
(2.828, 4.24) for the std.

Comment: @ThomasR - So it means if different length then what is expected output?

Comment: I made it sure, that the arrays have the same length. So do not worry about that.

Comment: @ThomasR - Then the best is create 2d array and count with it, it is impossible?

Comment: Sure, should be possible. I haven't tried it yet and I'd think that it might be pretty slow.

Comment: With loops it would work as well, but probably as well very slow

Comment: @ThomasR - I think it depends of your implementation, for me it is faster, edited answer.

Comment: How would you implement it?

Comment: @ThomasR - I think if working with many small groups in groupby it should be differnet like working with 20k rows 2d arrays ;)

Comment: @ThomasR - But if working with same length lists with same types like here the best is use numpy 2d arrays (if performance is important) or if need working per axis=0

Comment: thanks for your idea.
Inspired by your array idea, I found the following solution:
    print(np.array(df['array'].apply(list).to_list()).max(axis=0))
    print(np.array(df['array'].apply(list).to_list()).std(axis=0,ddof=1))
    
    > [ 5 14]
    > [2.82842712 4.24264069]

Comment: Although your array solution is faster